# Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In typescript, I got error of 
`Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.`

I want to add 'abc' into the array, what's wrong with it?

```
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("abc");
  const [arr, setArr] = React.useState([]);

  const xx = () => setArr([...arr, text]);

  return <div className="App">{text}</div>;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-spence-08g8r?file=/src/App.tsx:56-272

Comment: Use `React.useState<string[]>([])`

Answer (score 5):

`useState` is a generic function so use it to define the type of array.

like: `const [arr, setArr] = React.useState<string[]>([]);`

Comment: This is the recommended approach 

Answer (score 0):

```
  const initArr: string[] = [];
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("abc");
  const [arr, setArr] = React.useState(initArr);
```

just try to define your init array

Answer (score 0):

`const [arr, setArr] = React.useState([] as string[]);`

The compiler needs to know the type of the array.